# What do you call a layout in which columns expand on mouseover?

Tags: layout, terminology

What's the proper name for a layout like this, in which a column expands when mouse enters it: http://www.lucagiorcelli.it/test/volunia/

May be called "reactive layout"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would refer to this as another example of [Progressive Disclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure).

As a side note, [this article](http://baymard.com/blog/trigger-indicators) is a great resource for using proper indicators for hidden elements such as is the case with progressive disclosure.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [GotDibbs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/23087/60), this is an example of Progressive Disclosure. Although you are also partially correct in saying that it is a reactive layout. It's just that 'reactive layout' usually refers to the layout of the website changing on the fly to accommodate a smaller or larger area or screen size as apposed to the user interacting with individual elements.